# Can't install flashplayer on Debian Wheezy

Tags: linux, debian, flash-player

flashplayer is having trouble installing in Debian Wheezy. I need it to be able to watch certain videos on YouTube. It fails on a wget operation:

```
$ sudo aptitude install flashplugin-nonfree
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  flashplugin-nonfree 
0 packages upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/20.1 kB of archives. After unpacking 181 kB will be used.
Selecting previously unselected package flashplugin-nonfree.
(Reading database ... 149986 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking flashplugin-nonfree (from .../flashplugin-nonfree_1%3a3.2_amd64.deb) ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus ...
Setting up flashplugin-nonfree (1:3.2) ...
ERROR: wget failed to download http://people.debian.org/~bartm/flashplugin-nonfree/fp10.sha512.amd64.pgp.asc
More information might be available at:
  http://wiki.debian.org/FlashPlayer
```

I have made sure that `wget` is already installed too:

```
$ uname -a
Linux *pcname* 3.13-0.bpo.1-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.13.7-1~bpo70+1 (2014-03-29) x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list | grep non
deb http://ftp.au.debian.org/debian/ stable main contrib non-free
```

I can provide more information if required too. This is an HP notebook with a very new install of Debian Wheezy.

Comment: can u link your source list? /etc/apt/sources.list.

Answer (score 0):

Did you updated your source list before installation. if not update it. Add `deb ftp://ftp.debian.org/debian stable main contrib non-free` or `deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian wheezy main contrib`to the file `/etc/apt/sources.list` then run an update `sudo apt-get update` and then try to install flash player plugin `sudo apt-get install flashplugin-nonfree`